# Film seen on television sometime in the late 1970s with astronauts returning to a changed Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

The film was not "Planet of the Apes", but similar in that there is some sort of time-warp/dimensional travel. I remember that there were about six crew-members, and that the initial landing (after receiving no word from mission control) was sort of jungley.

Comment: My editing-car veered off the road at jungley.  As in, the landing was in a tree-like environment?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like one of Gene Roddenberry's pilots from the early 1970s, [*Strange New World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_New_World_(TV_pilot)).  I vaguely remember it and never saw it re-run.  It followed a theme from two previous Roddenberry attempts, based on the original [*Genesis II*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_(film)).

In *Genesis II*, Alex Cord, as Dylan Hunt, had designed a cryogenics process and volunteered for the test.  Things went wrong (didn't see that coming, right?), and he ends up frozen for over a century.  When he's brought back, Earth has been balkanized and there are different cultures all over.  While several sample episodes were produced (and sometimes combined to fill 2 hours and re-run as movies), the series didn't sell.

Later Roddenberry tried again with almost the same concept, using John Saxon as Dylan Hunt in [*Planet Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_(TV_pilot)).  This also didn't sell.  (And I have to admit my memory may be off, and it could be this pilot that I have mistaken for the sample episodes mentioned above.)

Three times a charm, right?  While Roddenberry didn't do the third try, they did try again with his ideas, and using John Saxon again as the lead, but this time naming the character Captain Anthony Vito (still of PAX, just as in the other two).  This attempt was called [*Strange New World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_(TV_pilot)).

In *Strange New World*, there was a space station.  The Wikipedia articles I linked to gives details better than I remember them.  What I do remember is that they came down from the space station to Earth, and were in a jungle environment and found some civilization and realized they'd basically be going from one city-state to the next trying to fix things and restore some kind of order.

It was about 25-30 years later when Majel Barrett Roddenberry finally brought the concept to the screen in a series that actually sold, with *Andromeda*, with Kevin Sorbo starring as Captain Hercules - er, Captain Dylan Hunt.

The original concept of all the variations grew directly from *Star Trek*.  Roddenberry had originally pitched Trek as "Wagon Train to the stars," meaning the crew would be wandering or on a long trek and would encounter dangers and threats and many different civilizations, with each civilization having their own unique problems that must be solved by our heroes.  Also, the concept of using peaceful means to solve the problems came from *Star Trek* and showed up in all three attempts to bring the story to the screen in the form of PAX, an organization dedicated to rebuilding Earth, but only through non-violent means.

This was the original idea behind *Andromeda*, too - rebuilding a lost civilization one culture at a time, but when Robert Hewitt Wolfe canned so they could dumb down the story lines, the whole concept of rebuilding a large civilization was sidelined.