# Is Blueshift based on an older film? Astronauts return to uninhabited earth after 800 years

Tags: story-identification, astronauts

When I read the 2018 novel [Blueshift](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/39327370-blueshift) by Joshua Dalzelle it seemed very familiar to me, to the point where I knew the ending before reading it. I'm certain it is based on an older movie, does anyone know what it might be?

Astronauts return to Earth after 800 years in space and sleep stasis abroad a private space ship, the Daedalus - they see the earth is dark. They get a signal says "No Earth" as they get close. There are evolved people on Mars that say they will help but they want the human history files aboard the Daedalus. Lot of infighting among the crew. There are human/creatures who think they are Gods from the stars and bring them offerings - deer, etc. Engraved skulls.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @MeatTrademark I'm guessing "what is the movie that has the same plot as the book *Blueshift*?"

Comment: What is the name of the movie that has this storyline

Comment: Could you list some of the plot points that felt familiar? Relying only on the description of "Blueshift", several stories sound similar, including "Earthsearch" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsearch

Comment: ok - the ship was built by a billionaire who decided that he could stay in the sleep stasis most of the time, his was special built, and come back as a super billionaire and famous and live well. The pilot and the science officer used to be married. They started with about 22 people and are down to 7. When they get close to earth they get that repeating signal "No Earth" but they don't get any reply as it is just a beacon. They get close to earth and it is dark, no lights on anywhere and this really scares them. They start getting a signal, broken english, saying they see them - this is mars

Comment: the science officer sees there are roaming beasts on earth, leopards in kentucky, etc. They run out of time and crash land, everyone survives but the young Indian tech guy has a broken arm. Later he is injured again and she is using all the ship's medical stores on him and the billionaire is furious. She tells him he is not rich anymore and has no skills. There are humanoid creatures throw rocks at the ship at night. They bring a dressed deer carcass

Comment: and our people realize that they think the Star People are from the Gods. Eventually one by one they all die off except the captain. The mars people are saying they can send a ship that has to be robotic as they can't land and can he bring the earth history files - they really want those. He decides he will stay on earth but sends them the files.

Comment: this is not too old - at least past 2000 - oh, they went to research a star called Angel-21

Comment: Which of those plot points or scenes made you think this is based on an older film?

Comment: This is not an old movie - I don’t understand the “which of” - this is a movie that exactly mirrors a book published June 2019. So the movie had to be made before the book which is supposed to be impossible in this situation. I was able in multiple areas of the book to know precisely what was coming next. I saw this on TV. I really want the name of the movie so I can prove I am not crazy.

Comment: This has a lot of similarities to this question, worth checking out, but not an exact match to your description of the book.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123158/movie-about-astronauts-returning-to-a-post-apocalyptic-earth-and-starting-to-fig