# 90s movie about astronauts returning a liquid sample from Venus

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think I saw this movie in the 90s on Hungarian TV.

It started with a team of astronauts on Venus. There's this thick green liquid and they collect a sample in a thermos bottle. As they do this, a rope snaps and a member of the team falls into a hole. With no way to save them, they decide to return to Earth rather than risks more losses.

They return to Earth and land in a desert. There is nobody to greet them. They walk and walk and walk. Everyone is delirious from thirst and tensions rise. They carry a flare gun and the bottle with the sample. They use a few flares but still nobody comes for them.

They descend into madness and die one by one. The last astronaut shoots and kills the other one with the flare gun. He walks on alone. He finds a well but it's dry. He ends up dramatically drinking the sample from Venus!

Then he arrives in a town? The movie ends.

Comment: I've been trying to track this down for a while now. With the news about life on Venus I cannot put this off any longer. But I can't find anything with Google. I may misremember some key details. But I'm super sure about the flare gun and drinking the sample!

Comment: There once was a liquid from Venus. Oh wait, I can't tell that joke.

Comment: Yes, I think I recall the climbing too! That must be it! It's totally possible it was the Moon and not Venus. Is there anything else you remember?

Comment: There's some good stuff in Planeta Bur (1962) too, which I just discovered. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RN14uPTPUWk Around 24 minutes a member of the expedition falls down. But they survive and don't collect a sample. And I think I would remember the fight with the pterodactyl!

Comment: Is it maybe a bit like this one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123158/movie-about-astronauts-returning-to-a-post-apocalyptic-earth-and-starting-to-fig

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much for the help. Looks like I may have missed the first half of the film. I’ll make up for it now! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number of elements resemble the German movie "[Operation Ganymed](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Ganymed)" (1977).

- It has the crater scene, although it's not at the beginning of the movie and (as the name implies) it takes place on Ganymede, not on Venus.
- They return to Earth and land in a desert. There is nobody to greet them. They walk and walk and walk. Everyone is delirious from thirst and tensions rise. They carry a flare gun and the bottle with the sample. They use a few flares but still nobody comes for them. => Check
- I think I saw this movie in the 90s on Hungarian TV. => It's a German movie of some notoriety, it is entirely possible that it would be shown in Hungary, although I have no proof of that
- They descend into madness and die one by one.  => Check (madness includes delirium, murder and cannibalism)
- Then he arrives in a town? => Check, the last survivor arrives in a Mexican suburb.

The sample from the crater is the MacGuffin of the movie, they lug it around all the way through their descent into madness. I have no recollection if the lone survivor drinks it in the end, but you can check for yourself on YouTube (the crater scene is around 1:30:00):

Comment: Ups, was already called out as a possible duplicate, although I still do not understand how dupes work here.

Comment: This looks like it! I'll give it a closer look and accept. Thanks so much!

Comment: 100% this is it, though I think I missed the first half. (May be the reason I couldn’t find it myself...) I forgot about the visions of grandeur, but now I remember them. It’s even crazier than I remembered. Thanks a lot for finding it.

Answer (score 3):

I've not seen it, but this looks like a possibility. I don't know if it has Venusian liquid, or flare gun, but it's got a walk through the desert.

[Aurora](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128059/?ref_=kw_li_tt)

> In the 22nd century, seven explorers set out on a mission to earth's nearest sister planet, AURORA. Their mission - to survey and explore for future colonization. When their ship suddenly malfunctions, the crew is forced to crash land on the planet's surface, where crippling heat, poisonous water, and fierce storms threaten their lives at every turn. With a handful of supplies and little hope of rescue, their only option is a grueling four hundred mile trek to their ship's lost supply bunkers. To survive, the men will have to push their endurance to the limit and entrust their lives to a leader who will risk everything to succeed, no matter what the consequences

Here's a trailer, does it look familiar?

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it's the one I saw. It certainly matches the trek through the desert with tensions high. And it looks really obscure too. But they are wearing office clothes! I think mine were in astronaut suits throughout. I could be wrong though. And Aurora's trailer doesn't mention a sample. I'll see if I can watch it anyway, just to be sure.

Comment: The whole movie is on YouTube! I've skimmed through it. Looks like they just walk through the desert through the whole movie. Wow. It doesn't look like it's the one I saw, but it's pretty interesting nonetheless.